# GP3 speed drops way below minimum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Cassandra server on a m5.large that constantly reads from disk.

The drive is a GP3 with 250MB/s and 3000 IOPS.

At some point it just drops to 77MB/s and only recovers after a reboot.

Any idea why?

LE: apparently iowait is very high, does this mean i'm tapped out as far as IOPS goes? should I get an io1/io2 disk?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the Amazon EC2 **instance type**? If it is in the T-Family, then it is a burstable instance and CPU throttling might be causing the issue.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it's an m5 but you're right, I should have mentioned the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like every EC2 instance type is capped at a certain bandwidth/IOPS when working with disks: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html.

This should be in the Launch Instance table, I've lost an insane amount of time debugging an issue also caused by this in the past.